# Combining Swordsage and Broken One Substitution Levels

Tags: dnd-3.5e, house-rules, class

I want to be able to offer my DM suggestions about how this can work mechanically. I want to use the Broken One monk substitution levels from *Champions of Valor* 36-7 but use *Tome of Battle*'s swordsage instead of monk. It seems that exchanging the swordsage class feature detect magic for the Broken One class feature locate creature at level 7 is reasonable, but what would be a fair house rule for the swordsage to acquire also the Broken One class features at levels 3 and 6 when at those levels the swordsage gains no special class features?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to ask this question -- since it's not part of the existing rules, what should answers be based on?  If a DM agrees to allow this combo, they're probably going to ask you to lose something in return, but that's entirely up to them.

Comment: Roll back the edit if this isn't the question's intent.

Comment: The intent seems to be pretty clear.. what's the problem?  He's asking how reasonable it is from a game-balance point of view to gain the Broken One Monk class features as a Swordsage.

Given that all it gives is Lay on Hands, Tenacious Tracker, and Locate Creature, it's very easy to weave that in.  Replace Insightful Strikes with Lay on Hands, and Sense Magic with Tenacious Tracker and Locate Creature.EDIT: Given the abilities are minor, you could even replace nothing, and the swordsage would be still basically the same balance level.

Comment: @JackLesnie I don't see the same intent in the original question. What user88995 askes was "what benefits do I get from applying this template to this class?", which can't be done by the rules. HeyICanChan's edit is different enought to require approval by the original querent.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that, lore-wise, a swordsage could be a member of the broken ones does not imply he could take a variant tought for a specific class.

What you need to acknowledge is that monks between the Broken Ones take the Broken One variant and this does not bar vanilla swordsages to be Broken One members.

If you wanted to get a swordsage variant for Broken One swordsage members, you should ask your DM for one. It's not automatic the benefits would be the same as the monk variant, just as there are different prestige classes aimed at differnt classes for memebers of other D&D orders (e.g. Nightsong Enforcer/Infiltrator).

Comment: -1: Unclear writing 'it's not automatic the benefits''monks between the Broken Ones', talking about lore and fluff in a mechanical question, insulting the asker.

Comment: The question has changed a lot since I answer it. I'm waiting for the querent to confirm the edit before touching anything in my answer.